# UIView appearing on multiple UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drawing, 2d, cell

i have a little social network and i tried to implement the ratings code into the table view, it judges ratings with stars... the problem is that the second section displays ratings from the first table section

picture:

[image]

so you can see it displays ratings in some of the tableview cells, just the last couple, why would it be doing this?

drawing code:

```
 -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
if(_shouldDrawRating)
{
    self.desc_image.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    self.desc_image.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _rating = [[UIStarRateView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220,35,70,15)];
    [_rating setMaxStars:5];
    [_rating setFullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFull.png"]];
    [_rating setHalfImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarHalf.png"]];
    [_rating setEmptyImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmpty.png"]];
    [_rating setRate:_postRating];
    [self addSubview:_rating];
}
}
```

cell rendering code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Regular_Cell *cell;
// Configure the cell...
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_RECENT)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"default"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"default"];
        }
        NSDictionary *dict = self.recentArray[indexPath.row];
        [cell setShouldDrawRating:YES];
        [cell.title_label setText:dict[@"title"]];;
        [cell.author_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@",dict[@"author"]]];
        [cell.views_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Views: %@",dict[@"views"]]];
        [cell setPoll_idFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict[@"id"]]];
        //options for image view
        cell.desc_image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict[@"imageURL"]]];
        [cell.desc_image setImageURL:imageURL];
        [cell setPostRating:indexPath.row+0.5];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_RECENT)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"See More"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"See More"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
}
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    if(indexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_TOP)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"default"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"default"];
        }
        NSDictionary *dict = self.topViewedArray[indexPath.row];
        [cell.title_label setText:dict[@"title"]];
        [cell.author_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@",dict[@"author"]]];
        [cell.views_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Views: %@",dict[@"views"]]];
        [cell setPoll_idFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict[@"id"]]];
        //options for image view
        cell.desc_image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict[@"imageURL"]]];
        [cell.desc_image setImageURL:imageURL];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_TOP)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"See More"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"See More"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In section 1 you have to set the boolean to NO,It doesnt have a proper value now in section 1.I think you  miss this line.

```
    [cell setShouldDrawRating:NO];
```

Not only in Section 1 where ever you create the cell it must be implemented,Otherwise can cause problem of inconsistency in drawing

Answer (score 0):

Replace code for setting cell labels, images etc from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and paste it in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. And `setShouldDrawRating:` in each section, not only in section number 0.